# What to write in CV when transferring between schools?

Tags: phd, cv

I'm transferring between two PhD programs, same program two different schools. I have done 4 years of study in the first school but have not (and will not) receive any degrees and I need to complete 1-2 years of study in the new school to get my PhD. Assume that the new school is more prestigious. I wrote this piece in my CV.

> 2010-Expected 2016 **PhD in Compute Science** from New University
>
> - PhD Student at Old University (2010-2014)
>
> 2007-2010 **MS in Computer Engineering** from Another university
>
> ...

However, the second line is kind of small and doesn't catch eye but if someone wants to read my CV it's there. The problem is I have not been student at New University since 2010 and I don't want to say that I'm a first year student. Also since I didn't get any degree from Old University I cannot have a separate entry for it.

Comment: My advisor told me to remove the years (2010-2014) and change phd -> phd student as I haven't received my phd yet :)

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is I have not been student at New University since 2010 and I don't want to say that I'm a first year student. Also since I didn't get any degree from Old University I cannot have a separate entry for it.

Why does it matter whether you got a degree from Old University?  There's no rule that says the education section of your CV can only be organized by degree.  You just need to be clear and honest.

What you propose doesn't seem inappropriate, but I think this might be slightly clearer:

2014-2016 (expected) **PhD in Computer Science** from New University

2010-2014 PhD student at Old University (transferred to New University)

2007-2010 **MS in Computer Engineering** from Another University

Answer (score 0):

May this format help you:

If "university major" is the university which is going to give you your degree and "university minor" is the one in which you have studied about four years;

> 2010 - 2016 (expected) **PhD in Computer Science**; university major
>
> [some space here] 2014 - 2016 university major
>
> [some space here] 2010 - 2014 university minor

However, I think that as you are not receiving any degree from your minor university, *and* its name is not going to be mentioned anywhere in your certificates; there is no need to bring it's name in your CV too, because you don't have any proof that you have studied there.

Comment: Disagree that you have no reason to list universities unless they awarded you a degree. An academic CV is a timeline of your whole career. If you spent four years studying in a university's PhD program it should be there.

Comment: it's listed somewhere else in my research experiences section but not in the education section.